# How to get scope identity column value in ssis using kingswaysoft

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am new to SSIS. I want to retrieve newly inserted value from destination CRM that is Identity column

My source is SQL server and destination is CRM database

Comment: My source is SQL server and destination is CRM database

Comment: How exactly are you inserting it? Through an ADO.Net connection? Through a SQL task? Are you inserting a batch of records or only one? Do you _have_ to use Kingswaysoft to find it?

Comment: Right now I am using kingswaysoft for inserting in to destination CRM it creates guid primary key . I want that key for reference to insert in to child tables

Comment: So I guess you have a dataflow feeding into that, which means you have a bunch of records going in. Kingswaysoft would have to have an output for this. If it doesn't (which is likely) then you need to use other methods such as staging tables or script to do this. Even this is a common requirement, I've never found a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `CrmRecordId` column in the output of the `destination` component. This means you can't see it in the Insert component, but you can access it in child steps.

There is also an `IsNew` column that may be of use (e.g. if you're doing an `Upsert`)

[image]

1. Shows the Insert / Upsert Kingswaysoft Step
2. Shows the destination component
3. shows the available columns including `CrmRecordId` and `IsNew`

Answer (score 1):

In your destination step, you will find a checkbox for CrmRecordId. It will be check by default.

[image]

Then, you can use the id from the destination node. In my case, I count the number I created and log the guids.

[image]

Comment: I've never used Kingswaysoft before - that _actually_ looks pretty useful.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it is also possible to store source primarykey id and destination keyid after record moved in to destination?

Comment: Yes it is and that is how I do it with staging tables. However the source key needs to be stored in a column in the target table - that's the only way you can know which row got which ID. I doubt you can add columns to Dynamics tables